# SMS notification not working with Arduino Nano with a GSM module

Tags: arduino, sms, gsm, at-command

I want to use an Arduino Nano to monitor SMS traffic of a GSM module. I'm able to read and send SMS but the notification system is not working: when I send an SMS (to the SIM card that is in the GSM module) no new data becomes available in the Serial port. Any idea why or how can I debug to find the problem?

The communication is done through pins 9 and 10 of Arduino and RX and TX for the GSM module, which is an Quectel EC25. The code I'm using:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG Serial
SoftwareSerial EC25(10,9); // RX, TX - 9600 baud rate
// pin 8 of raspi -> pin 9 of arduino nano 
// pin 10 of raspi -> pin 10 of arduino nano

#define AT_RESPONSE_LEN 100
#define TIMEOUT 1000

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  EC25.begin(9600);
  DEBUG.begin(9600);

  // some AT commands just to see if the coms are ok
  sendATComm("AT","OK\r\n");
  sendATComm("AT+IPR?","OK\r\n");
  sendATComm("AT+CGSN","OK\r\n");

  sendATComm("AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0","OK\r\n");

  DEBUG.println("listennig");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if (EC25.available()){
    DEBUG.println("Notification received!");
  }

}



// function for sending at command.
const char* sendATComm(const char *command, const char *desired_reponse)
{
  uint32_t timer;
  char response[AT_RESPONSE_LEN]; // module response for AT commands.

  memset(response, 0 , AT_RESPONSE_LEN);
  EC25.flush();

  sendATCommOnce(command);

  timer = millis();
   while(true){
    if(millis()-timer > TIMEOUT){
      sendATCommOnce(command);
      timer = millis();
    }
    char c;
    int i = 0;

    while(EC25.available()){
      c = EC25.read();
      DEBUG.write(c);
      response[i++]=c;
      delay(2);
      }
      if(strstr(response, desired_reponse)){
        return response;
        memset(response, 0 , strlen(response));
        break;
      }
  }
}

// send at comamand to module
void sendATCommOnce(const char *comm)
{
  EC25.print(comm);
  EC25.print("\r");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: _ "when I send an SNS (to the SIM card that is in the GSM module) no new data becomes available in the Serial port"_ - What does it mean? You receive the SMS (you can read it later) but you don't receive the URC?

Comment: I'm able to read the SMS with an AT command. The problem is that I want to listen to the notification when a new SMS arrives.

Comment: When I wrote *URC* I was talking about Unsolicited Result Codes (=notifications). The `+CNMI` setting seems correct. When you say that you _"read  the SMS with an AT command"_, does it mean that you sent the AT command using your routines? In other words, do your functions work? If the answer is _yes_, I have only one check to suggest: the only reason that might prevent `+CMTI` URC for an SMS correctly received is that the SMS memory is full. Could you check it, please?

Comment: A related question (and answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908575/cnmi-command-how-to-receive-notification-and-save-to-sim-card-incoming-sms .

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Yes, I can read the SMS with the functions. The problem is that when it receives an SMS no data notification data is sent to the serial EC25 and consequently the `available()` method output nothing. It can't be related to the SIM card because the same is working with an alternative GSM module (SIM7600).  But perhaps the notifications are saved somewhere in the module?

Comment: Not the notifications, the sms themselves. If the memory card is full, no notification is sent. `AT+CPMS?` should provide you the occupied space for every SMS storage.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, check the answer. It was related to the URC port. I'm using RX and TX to communicate and the notification was being sent to another port.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that feature. It is not standard behavior.. Please, improve you answer so that other people can find it useful. Explain better the command behaviour, and what are the default values. Add a the modified version of your code including the command that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that I had to define the output port of URC to use UART communication (not using it as default).

The default configuration was set to either `usbat` or `usbmodem`, meaning that the notification information I was waiting for was being sent to one of these serial ports. But I was listening to UART (through RX and TX pints) and therefore I was not getting any notification.

AT command `QURCCFG` can be used to set which port URC signals should be sent to. In this case I want them to be sent to UART:

```
AT+QURCCFG="urcport","uart1"
```

Comment: Now it is better. Upvoted for the effort to research and improve it.